# iTextSharp: Is there a method that allows you to change the content of the page PDF document?

Tags: itext

I need to clear (delete text) a rectangular area of the document. Coordinates are known. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it actually required that the text is removed? Or does it suffice to cover it with a white rectangle?

Comment: Important to delete text.

Comment: IText (Sharp) does not contain convenience methods for that. It does offer a low level API, though, which allows you to implement that feature having quite some weight already taken from your shoulders.

Comment: Bad.. Then is it possible to alter the document so that the text was seen as pictures? And then put on these pictures rectangle..

Comment: Well, of course you can use some PDF library to render the page as an image, then erase the rectangle area in the image and then create a PDF containing that image. But that would be a really lossy procedure.

Comment: I need to solve this problem by using itextsharp. There is text on the page pdf-document that need to hide or remove. Tell me please what method can solve this problem?

Comment: Using iText (sharp) and not being allowed to not simply cover the characters is much more than just calling a single method. Have a close look at the parser package to see how content parsing happens, and add functionality to it which changes the content in your target area. an interesting task...

Comment: Can I install the copy protection for the document?

Comment: What kind of copy protection do you mean? Protection from copy & paste, from generic text extraction, or from file copy? I had a different idea recently how you might remove that text from view: You could try and apply a clipping path excluding the rectangle in question. I haven't done that yet and, therefore, don't know for certain whether the characters clipped away are selectable by copy&paste; they shouldn't be, though. Of course those characters still are extractable by generic text extraction mechanisms, but if preventing copy&paste suffices in your use case...

Comment: If I will protect the document from copying text and will draw a rectangle in the right area, then I will decide my problem. How can I protect the document from copying text using ITEXTSHARP?

Comment: Have a look at [EncryptionPdf.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter12&ex=EncryptionPdf) and use a **null** user password (allowing anyone to open the file but with merely the given permissions not including **ALLOW_COPY**). That sample is the C#ified version of [EncryptionPdf.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219) from chapter 12 of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

Comment: I set the Encryption stamper.setEncryption(Null,Null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128). But other programs can remove protection from a document. This means that the problem can not be solved by this method...

Comment: What about my idea from two days aga: *You could try and apply a clipping path excluding the rectangle in question.*